# How to drag a View down (only vertical) and scale another one above it at the same time in Android?

Tags: android, scale, drag, ontouchlistener

I have a complex view composed of other different Views. I would like to bea ble to drag vertically one view to scale another View that is above it. Hope that this graphic I made explains the situation I need to achieve.  [See graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQnnm.jpg)
 . I tried with drag and drop but I only one to drag it vertically. I also tried with onTouchListener. I was a little bit hard sin View 2 is a ViewPager, so I made a trick adding a transparent image at the top of View 2  with the ontouchlistener, and I couldn't achive a smooth movement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. Why would attaching the same onTouch listener to all 3 views and then resizing each one after a touch action not work? Add something like the touch listener below and then instead of animations resize each view's size or relative weight within the same parent view.

```
public class ViewFlipperSwipeDetector : FooClass, View.IOnTouchListener
{


    //private Activity activity;
    private ViewFlipper viewflipper;
    int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;


    public ViewFlipperSwipeDetector(ViewFlipper viewflipper)
    {
        //this.activity = activity;
        this.viewflipper = viewflipper;

    }

   private Animation inFromRightAnimation() 
   {
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, +1.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f,
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);

    inFromRight.Duration = 400;
    inFromRight.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return inFromRight;
    }

    private Animation outToLeftAnimation() 
    {
     Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
     Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, -1.0f,
     Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);

    outtoLeft.Duration = 400;
    outtoLeft.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return outtoLeft;
    }

    private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() 
    {
    Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, -1.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f,
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);
    inFromLeft.Duration = 400;
    inFromLeft.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return inFromLeft;
    }

    private Animation outToRightAnimation() 
    {
    Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, +1.0f,
     Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);
    outtoRight.Duration = 400;
    outtoRight.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return outtoRight;
    }

    protected void onRightToLeftSwipe()
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "RightToLeftSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        viewflipper.InAnimation = inFromRightAnimation();
        viewflipper.OutAnimation = outToLeftAnimation();
        viewflipper.ShowNext();

    }

    protected void onLeftToRightSwipe()
    {

       // Toast.MakeText(activity, "LeftToRightSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        viewflipper.InAnimation = inFromLeftAnimation();
        viewflipper.OutAnimation = outToRightAnimation();
        viewflipper.ShowPrevious();

    }

    protected void onTopToBottomSwipe()
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "TopToBottomSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        //activity.doSomething();
    }

    protected void onBottomToTopSwipe()
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "BottomToTopSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        //activity.doSomething();
    }


    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                {
                    downX = e.GetX();
                    downY = e.GetY();
                    return true;
                }
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                {
                    upX = e.GetX();
                    upY = e.GetY();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;
                    float deltaY = downY - upY;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        // left or right
                        if (deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(); return true; }
                        if (deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "Swipe was only " + Math.Abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        return false; 
                    }

                    // swipe vertical?
                    if (Math.Abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        // top or down
                        if (deltaY < 0) { this.onTopToBottomSwipe(); return true; }
                        if (deltaY > 0) { this.onBottomToTopSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "Swipe was only " + Math.Abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE, ToastLength.Short);
                        return false; 
                    }

                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code to apply to my case. but how can I scale the upper View progressively at the same time of dragging(or touching down + moving)? Could I do it changing LayoutParams when Touch (down) without noticing steps? Thanks for your response

Comment: I don't understand even the first line in the class declaration: `: FooClass, View.IOnTouchListener `

Comment: : is inherits in c# and , is extends. In your case you only need to extend IOnTouchListener the inheritence is just relative to my project i pulled this from.

Comment: Add a single on touch listener to the 3 views you want to resize on touch and in OnTouch resize the views relative to each other. If view 1 selected and motion is down event view1.height = view1.height + fling length, view2.height = view2.height - (fling length / 2), view3.height = view3.height - (fling length / 2)